# How to properly split translation files when using next-i18next

Tags: next.js, translation, i18next, next-i18next

I've noticed that NextJS is giving me this warning: **Warning: data for page "/details/[id]" (path "/details/19") is 425 kB which exceeds the threshold of 128 kB, this amount of data can reduce performance.**.

I believe this is probably because of my translation files. What I've been doing is using https://i18nexus.com/ to keep all ma translations and pulling them during build time. This is a page that holds the translations that next-i18next will use on pages.

I've split my translations into three files: description, common and footer.

What I believe the root cause of that warning is that I'm loading the whole description file when I load individual descriptions.

For instance, I'm visiting the page /details/19, so I only need the description-19 from the description JSON file. While on the page I'm loading the whole file:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context: any) {
    const response = await InformationService.getLocationWithWorkTime(context.params.id);

    return {
        props: {
            ...(await serverSideTranslations(context.locale, ['common', 'description', 'footer'])),
            information: response,
            revalidate: 3600,
            notFound: !response
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to lower the amount of data that I'm loading for translations? I have around 200 locations and each of them has a description translation in 3 languages, that is between 800 and 1500 characters long.

<kbd>**Note: This description data isn't changing, ever, so that's why I'm using next-i18next.**</kbd>